# Activate Grub to show up at start up?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, grub

I used to have both windows vista and ubuntu 10.04 on my laptop and i could choose which one to start at start up.
But now I only have ubuntu 10,04 on my laptop and because there is only one operating system on my laptop the grub window doesn't show up.
I need it because sometimes I need to start my ubuntu in recovery mode with no graphics, I checked and grub is already installed, how can I activate it at start up ?

( by the way : I have grub2 )

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The menu will appear if you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> when grub is loaded. By default you have 10 seconds.

If you want to always see the menu, edit `/etc/default/grub`. [The settings are documented on the Ubuntu website.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Configuring%20GRUB%202) You may want to:

- Set `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false` so that Grub shows a countdown to the automatic boot. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> during the countdown to make the menu appear.
- Set `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=` (nothing after the equal sign) to always display the menu.
- Change the setting for `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` (number of seconds before the automatic boot). The value `-1` means that there will be no automatic boot.

Note that spaces are not allowed on either side of the equal sign.

You need to run the `update-grub` command for the settings to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

or you can just hit [shift] during boot when you need to choose boot options so you dont have to worry about it the rest of the time

Comment: ESC is for Grub1. Use Shift for Grub2.